# Property of a variable in class seems to be undeclared

Tags: c++, box2d

I have a class `Object`, inside it I declare a variable of type `b2Shape`, which has two public properties like this:

```
class b2Shape{  
public:  
  [other methods]  
  Type m_type;  
  float32 m_radius;  
};
```

Inside Object I declare it this way:

```
class Object{  
public:  
  [other methods]  
  b2Shape* shape;  
  void printR(){  
    cout<<shape.m_radius;  
  }  
};
```

When I create an instance of Object, I pass a `b2Shape` by reference to `shape` var, but inside Object I can't access `shape`'s properties (by calling `printR()` for example). The compiler says they're undeclared, why this happens? Here's the code where I create the Object instance:

```
Object ball;  
b2Shape ballBox;  
ballBox.m_radius = 18;  
ball.shape = &ballBox;
```

Comment: Tried dereferencing ball.shape? E.g. ball.shape->m_radius . Can't test it right now.

Comment: Glad I could help. Created an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to dereference the pointer. In ball.shape there will only be saved an adress of the  b2Shape object's instance. This is why you ned to use:

```
ball.shape->m_radius
```